# The best way to use the lineinfile module for all hosts

Tags: ansible

I need the playbook I wrote to include the text output file plus my hostname, which works correctly, but only for one of the hosts. If anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

```yaml
---
- name: Check for 2023 in zdump output
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Run zdump command
      command: zdump -v Asia/Tehran
      register: zdump_output
      ignore_errors: yes 

    - name: Check if 2023 exists in the output
      set_fact:
        is_2023_exists: "{{ '2023' in zdump_output.stdout }}"

    - name: Display message if 2023 does not exist
      debug:
        msg: "2023 exist in zdump output."
      when: not is_2023_exists


    - name: Save the message in output.txt
      lineinfile:
            path: /home/fshamsian/output.txt
            line: "{{ ansible_host_var  }}: 2023 did not exist \n"
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: not is_2023_exists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variable named `ansible_host_var`; I would expect the playbook you show in your question to fail with:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_host_var' is undefined.

You're probably looking for the `inventory_hostname` variable; which would look like this:

```yaml
    - name: Save the message in output.txt
      lineinfile:
        path: ./output.txt
        line: >-
          {{ inventory_hostname  }}: 2023 did not exist
        create: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: not is_2023_exists
```

But this is problematic. If we have an inventory file with three nodes:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    node0:
    node1:
    node2:
```

And if we run this playbook a few times, each time starting with an empty `output.txt` file, we will sometimes see a single entry, sometimes two entries, and sometimes three entries. This is because we have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition): Ansible is running multiple instances of this task in parallel, and these concurrent tasks clobber each other's output.

We can avoid this problem by replacing the `lineinfile` task with a template task. For example:

```yaml
- name: Check for 2023 in zdump output
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Run zdump command
      command: zdump -v Asia/Tehran
      register: zdump_output
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Check if 2023 exists in the output
      set_fact:
        is_2023_exists: "{{ '2023' in zdump_output.stdout }}"

- name: Write output
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Save the message in output.txt
      copy:
        dest: ./output.txt
        content: |
          {% for host in groups.all %}
          {% if not hostvars[host].is_2023_exists %}
          {{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}: 2023 did not exist
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

This will reliably produce the desired output because there is only a single task responsible for writing to the output file.

Answer (score 2):

A follow up to [larsk's answer](/a/77121758/9401096) for the sake of completeness. The solution given is definitely the most adapted and the most efficient in your current scenario to overcome the explained race condition.

Meanwhile it is possible to avoid that race condition still using `lineinfile`. If you don't mind loosing a bit of performance in this specific case, you can [throttle the number of workers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle) for the task to 1 so that there is no parallel execution:

```yaml
    - name: Save the message in output.txt
      lineinfile:
        path: ./output.txt
        line: >-
          {{ inventory_hostname  }}: 2023 did not exist
        create: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: not is_2023_exists
      throttle: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Use the lineinfile module for all hosts."***

A: [Create a dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data) of [all hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and their [values of the variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) *is_2023_exists*

```yaml
  is_2023_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                         zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                             map('extract', hostvars, 'is_2023_exists'))) }}"
```

Then, use it in the loop. You avoid any hazards and still use the module *lineinfile*

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/output.txt
        line: "{{ item.key }}: 2023 did not exist"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ is_2023_dict|dict2items|rejectattr('value') }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

**Example of a complete project for testing.**

Given the inventory below, omit the collection of the variable *is_2023_exists* and focus on writing the file

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    node1:
      is_2023_exists: true
    node2:
      is_2023_exists: false
    node3:
      is_2023_exists: true
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    is_2023_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                           zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                               map('extract', hostvars, 'is_2023_exists'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: is_2023_dict
      run_once: true

    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/output.txt
        line: "{{ item.key }}: 2023 did not exist"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ is_2023_dict|dict2items|rejectattr('value') }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  is_2023_dict:
    node1: true
    node2: false
    node3: true
```

and creates the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/output.txt 
node2: 2023 did not exist
```